# How to get total number of tables in a hive database?

Tags: hive, hiveql, hive-metastore

Is it possible to get total number of hive tables ,if it's yes how to get?

Comment: That's possible using the Java API to the Metastore -- and developing a custom Java or Scala program...

Comment: Not possible as such when using a HQL command; Hive commands that access metadata do not return a tabular dataset that can then be massaged in SQL (like Oracle or SQL Server do) but simply "print" information. At least in `hive` and `beeline` clients -- but if you develop a custom Java or Scala or Python or C# 
program that connects to HiveServer2 with JDBC or DBI or ODBC, then it becomes possible

Comment: The same using shell (one-liner): https://stackoverflow.com/a/34632292/2700344

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the number of tables created in a database in hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469117/how-to-find-the-number-of-tables-created-in-a-database-in-hive)