# How to find out Total size of the Hive Database

Tags: database, hadoop, hive

i have a database with 10 tables. all 10 tables data is stored in different different locations. out of 10 tables, some are managed tables and some are external tables.

some tables location is /apps/hive/warehouse/

some tables location is /warehouse/hive/managed/

some tables location is /warehouse/hive/external/

is there any way to find out total size of the database with out go into each location and find the size, any alternative?

Comment: This can be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/34632292/2700344 And this is example how to parse location: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43804621/2700344

Answer (score 1):

The below query when run in the Hive Metastore DB would help you in getting the total size occupied by all the tables in Hive. **Note**: The results you get for this query would be 100% correct only if all the tables are having their stats updated. [This can be checked in the table - TABLE_PARAMS in Metastore DB that I have also mentioned below (How it works?.b)]

**Steps:**

**1.** Login into Hive Metastore DB and use the database that is used by hive. `hive1` by default.

**2.** Once done, you can execute the below query to get the total size of all the tables in Hive in bytes. The query takes the sum of total size of all the Hive tables based on the statistics of the tables.

````
    MariaDB [hive1]> SELECT SUM(PARAM_VALUE) FROM TABLE_PARAMS WHERE PARAM_KEY="totalSize";
    +------------------+
    | SUM(PARAM_VALUE) |
    +------------------+
    |   30376289388684 |
    +------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)```
````

**3.** Remember, the result derived above is for only one replication. 30376289388684 x 3 is the actual size in HDFS including the replication.

**How it works?**

a. Selecting a random table in Hive with id 5783 and name - test12345 from the TBLS table in Hive Metastore DB.

```
    MariaDB [hive1]> SELECT * FROM TBLS WHERE TBL_ID=5783;
    +--------+-------------+-------+------------------+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+
    | TBL_ID | CREATE_TIME | DB_ID | LAST_ACCESS_TIME | OWNER | RETENTION | SD_ID | TBL_NAME  | TBL_TYPE      | VIEW_EXPANDED_TEXT | VIEW_ORIGINAL_TEXT | LINK_TARGET_ID |
    +--------+-------------+-------+------------------+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+
    |   5783 |  1555060992 |     1 |                0 | hive  |         0 | 17249 | test12345 | MANAGED_TABLE | NULL               | NULL               |           NULL |
    +--------+-------------+-------+------------------+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

b. Checking the different parameters of the table in Hive Metastore table - TABLE_PARAMS for the same Hive table with id - 5783. The totalSize record indicates the total size occupied by this table in HDFS for one of its replica. The next point (c) which is the hdfs du -s  can be compared to check this.

The param `COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE` with the value `true` says the table's statistics property is set to true. You can check for tables with this value as `false` to see if there are any tables in Hive those might have missing statistics.

```
MariaDB [hive1]> SELECT * FROM TABLE_PARAMS
    -> WHERE TBL_ID=5783;
+--------+-----------------------+-------------+
| TBL_ID | PARAM_KEY             | PARAM_VALUE |
+--------+-----------------------+-------------+
|   5783 | COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE | true        |
|   5783 | numFiles              | 1           |
|   5783 | numRows               | 1           |
|   5783 | rawDataSize           | 2           |
|   5783 | totalSize             | 324         |
|   5783 | transient_lastDdlTime | 1555061027  |
+--------+-----------------------+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

c. `hdfs du -s` output of the same table from HDFS. 324 and 972 are the sizes of one and three replicas of the table data in HDFS.

```
324  972  /user/hive/warehouse/test12345
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: In what scenario, Hive table stats not be updated in Metastore? or does it takes some time to get updated? I have a lot of tables which shows 0 size on query but are occupying space in HDFS

Comment: Usually when new files are added in the HDFS Path of the table directly (i.e., using HDFS commands or so), Hive Metastore is not made aware of it. Running a MSCK REPAIR on such tables would update the metadata in Metastore.